# How do I get the icon associated with a file type?

Tags: c#, icons, file-association

I have a form that displays file information in a TabControl, and I'd like the pages to have the file's icon in their tab.  How do I get the icon associated with a file type?

I'd prefer solutions that don't involve looking things up in the registry, but if that's the only way then so be it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/System_File_Association.aspx) has some classes you can download.

First get the `FileAssociationInfo`, and from that get the `ProgramAssociationInfo`.  The `pai` object can give you the icon.

```
FileAssociationInfo fai = new FileAssociationInfo(".bob");
ProgramAssociationInfo pai = new ProgramAssociationInfo(fai.ProgID);
ProgramIcon icon = pai.DefaultIcon;
```

Comment: Looks good, but how do I get the FileAssociationInfo?  There's nothing on MSDN about any of those classes.

Comment: Here you can download the classes: http://channel9.msdn.com/playground/Sandbox/249856-System-File-Association/

Comment: My bad, I forgot to include the link.

Comment: Is this a cross-platform solution to this problem, or is it Windows-specific?

Answer (score 10):

[System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(string filePath)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon.aspx)

Comment: Is this Windows-specific? If so, is there a cross-platform solution?

Comment: That fails when the file does not exist. This becomes a problem when the file does not exist - because there is no file.