# How to get icon and description from file extension using Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi, icons, file-association

Basically I have a TcxGrid which will be listing various files names and I'd like to give further details based on the file extension, specifically it's description (e.g. for .PDF it's "Adobe Acrobat Document") and it's related icon.

I notice there is a [very similar question already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272035/how-do-i-get-the-icon-associated-with-a-file-type) but it's C# related and I'd like something Delphi based.

Suggestions on where to look for this kind of info would be good and if there is a class similar to the one mentioned in the C# post above (obviously in Delphi) that would be great.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thanks to Rob Kennedy for pointing me in the direction of ShGetFileInfo. I then Googled on that and found these two examples - [Delphi 3000](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_1086.asp?SK=), [Torry's](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=421). From that I wrote the following class to do what I needed.

Also, just as I was finishing up Bill Miller's answer gave me the final bit of help I needed. Originally I was passing full file names through to ShGetFileInfo, which wasn't ideally what I wanted. The tweak suggested of passing "*.EXT" was great.

The class could do with more work but it does what I need. It seems to handle file extensions that have no details associated either.

Finally, in what I'm using I've switched it to using a TcxImageList instead of a TImageList, since I was having problems with black borders appearing on the icons, because it was a quick fix.

```
unit FileAssociationDetails;

{
  Created       : 2009-05-07
  Description   : Class to get file type description and icons.
                  * Extensions and Descriptions are held in a TStringLists.
                  * Icons are stored in a TImageList.

                  Assumption is all lists are in same order.
}

interface

uses Classes, Controls;

type
  TFileAssociationDetails = class(TObject)
  private
    FImages : TImageList;
    FExtensions : TStringList;
    FDescriptions : TStringList;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure AddFile(FileName : string);
    procedure AddExtension(Extension : string);    
    procedure Clear;    
    procedure GetFileIconsAndDescriptions;

    property Images : TImageList read FImages;
    property Extensions : TStringList read FExtensions;
    property Descriptions : TStringList read FDescriptions;
  end;

implementation

uses SysUtils, ShellAPI, Graphics, Windows;

{ TFileAssociationDetails }

constructor TFileAssociationDetails.Create;
begin
  try
    inherited;

    FExtensions := TStringList.Create;
    FExtensions.Sorted := true;
    FDescriptions := TStringList.Create;
    FImages := TImageList.Create(nil);
  except
  end;
end;

destructor TFileAssociationDetails.Destroy;
begin
  try
    FExtensions.Free;
    FDescriptions.Free;
    FImages.Free;
  finally
    inherited;
  end;
end;

procedure TFileAssociationDetails.AddFile(FileName: string);
begin
  AddExtension(ExtractFileExt(FileName));
end;

procedure TFileAssociationDetails.AddExtension(Extension : string);
begin
  Extension := UpperCase(Extension);
  if (Trim(Extension) <> '') and
     (FExtensions.IndexOf(Extension) = -1) then
    FExtensions.Add(Extension);
end;

procedure TFileAssociationDetails.Clear;
begin
  FExtensions.Clear;
end;

procedure TFileAssociationDetails.GetFileIconsAndDescriptions;
var
  Icon: TIcon;
  iCount : integer;
  Extension : string;
  FileInfo : SHFILEINFO; 
begin
  FImages.Clear;
  FDescriptions.Clear;

  Icon := TIcon.Create;
  try
    // Loop through all stored extensions and retrieve relevant info
    for iCount := 0 to FExtensions.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Extension := '*' + FExtensions.Strings[iCount];

      // Get description type
      SHGetFileInfo(PChar(Extension),
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                    FileInfo,
                    SizeOf(FileInfo),
                    SHGFI_TYPENAME or SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES
                    );
      FDescriptions.Add(FileInfo.szTypeName);

      // Get icon and copy into ImageList
      SHGetFileInfo(PChar(Extension),
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                    FileInfo,
                    SizeOf(FileInfo),
                    SHGFI_ICON or SHGFI_SMALLICON or
                    SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX or SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES
                    );
      Icon.Handle := FileInfo.hIcon;
      FImages.AddIcon(Icon);
    end;
  finally
    Icon.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Also here is an example test app using it, it's very simple, just a form with a TPageControl on it. My actual use was not for this, but for with a Developer Express TcxImageComboxBox in a TcxGrid.

```
unit Main;

{
  Created       : 2009-05-07
  Description   : Test app for TFileAssociationDetails.
}

interface

uses
  Windows, Forms, FileAssociationDetails, Classes, Controls, ComCtrls;

type
  TfmTest = class(TForm)
    PageControl1: TPageControl;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FFileDetails : TFileAssociationDetails;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  fmTest: TfmTest;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfmTest.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  iCount : integer;
  NewTab : TTabSheet;
begin
  FFileDetails := TFileAssociationDetails.Create;
  FFileDetails.AddFile('C:\Documents and Settings\...\Test.XLS');
  FFileDetails.AddExtension('.zip');
  FFileDetails.AddExtension('.pdf');
  FFileDetails.AddExtension('.pas');
  FFileDetails.AddExtension('.XML');
  FFileDetails.AddExtension('.poo');

  FFileDetails.GetFileIconsAndDescriptions;
  PageControl1.Images := FFileDetails.Images;

  for iCount := 0 to FFileDetails.Descriptions.Count - 1 do
  begin
    NewTab := TTabSheet.Create(PageControl1);
    NewTab.PageControl := PageControl1;
    NewTab.Caption := FFileDetails.Descriptions.Strings[iCount];
    NewTab.ImageIndex := iCount;
  end;
end;

procedure TfmTest.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  PageControl1.Images := nil;
  FFileDetails.Free;
end;

end.
```

Thanks everyone for your answers!

Comment: A note: when passing full filenames, shortcuts like '%1' as a shortcut for icon or bitmap files will yield the correct result for each specific file.  *.ext will just show a generic icon in such cases.

Comment: @Martijn, What do you mean by using '%1'? Can you show an example?

Comment: @pcunite: I now see that my comment wasn't very clear.  In some cases, "%1" is defined as DefaultIcon for a file type; this is usually the case for `.ico` files: each icon file itself contains the icon to display. In such a case, using the full filename will yield the correct icon. Using only the extension here would result in a 'generic' icon.

Answer (score 3):

Call [`ShGetFileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762179.aspx). It can tell you the description (the "type name," in that function's vocabulary), and it can give you an icon handle, or a handle to the system image list, where the icon resides, or the path to the module that holds the image resource. That function can do lots of different things, so make sure to read the documentation carefully.

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761854(VS.85).aspx) `ShGetFileInfo` "may be slow" and calls the [`IExtractIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761854(VS.85).aspx) interface a "more flexible and efficient" alternative. But the sequence it recommends is to use an [`IShellFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775075.aspx) interface, then call [`GetUIObjectOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775073.aspx) to get the file's `IExtractIcon` interface, and then call [`GetIconLocation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761852.aspx) and [`Extract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761850.aspx) on it to retrieve the icon's handle.

For all I know, that's exactly what `ShGetFileInfo` does anyway, but it's much more cumbersome, and after you've done all that, you still wouldn't have the file's type description. Stick with `ShGetFileInfo` until speed and efficiency become a noticeable problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
function GetGenericFileType( AExtension: string ): string;
{ Get file type for an extension }
var
  AInfo: TSHFileInfo;
begin
  SHGetFileInfo( PChar( AExtension ), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, AInfo, SizeOf( AInfo ),
    SHGFI_TYPENAME or SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES );
  Result := AInfo.szTypeName;
end;

function GetGenericIconIndex( AExtension: string ): integer;
{ Get icon index for an extension type }
var
  AInfo: TSHFileInfo;
begin
  if SHGetFileInfo( PChar( AExtension ), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, AInfo, SizeOf( AInfo ),
    SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX or SHGFI_SMALLICON or SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES ) <> 0 then
  Result := AInfo.iIcon
  else
    Result := -1;
end;

function GetGenericFileIcon( AExtension: string ): TIcon;
{ Get icon for an extension }
var
  AInfo: TSHFileInfo;
  AIcon: TIcon;
begin
  if SHGetFileInfo( PChar( AExtension ), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, AInfo, SizeOf( AInfo ),
    SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX or SHGFI_SMALLICON or SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES ) <> 0 then
  begin
    AIcon := TIcon.Create;
    try
      AIcon.Handle := AInfo.hIcon;
      Result := AIcon;
    except
      AIcon.Free;
      raise;
    end;
  end
  else
    Result := nil;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Bill for both your answers. I noticed you'd been able to pass just the extension to SHGetFileInfo (I was using full file names) and so I tweaked my code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
uses ShellAPI;

var
AExtension: string;
AFileType: string;    
AListItem: TListItem;
AFileInfo: TSHFileInfo;
begin
// get the extensions file icon
AExtension := ExtractFileExt( FileName );
if SHGetFileInfo( PChar( '*' + AExtension ), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, AFileInfo, SizeOf
  ( AFileInfo ), SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX or SHGFI_SMALLICON or SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES ) <> 0 then
  AIndex := AFileInfo.iIcon
else
  AIndex := -1;
AListItem.ImageIndex := AIndex;
// get extensions file info
if SHGetFileInfo( PChar( '*' + AExtension ), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, Info, SizeOf( Info ),
  SHGFI_TYPENAME or SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES ) then
    AFileType := AFileInfo.szTypeName;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not to sound glib, but Google is your friend.  Here are a couple of the first results for "delphi associated icon":

http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_453.asp?SK=

http://www.jpgriffiths.com/tutorial/Snippets%5Cgetassociatedicon.html

Comment: Thanks Bruce for the pointers, unfortunately that's not exactly what I was after. I was after the description too. Also, I just thought I'd try StackOverflow, see what Delphi expertise it has, I don't think it's done too badly!

Answer (score 0):

The other method is to hunt down the extension in the registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, then follow the key in the default value (if available) and its default is the description.  This second level is also where you can get the shell commands to open, or print the file type as well as the path to the default icon.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple good examples of using ShGetFileInfo from bitwisemag.com:

http://www.bitwisemag.com/copy/delphi/lpad1.html

http://www.bitwisemag.com/copy/delphi/prog_groups2.html