# Path for ShellExecute of IExplorer.exe

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, shellexecute

I want to use ShellExecute iexplore.exe (with an html file name as a command line arg), even if iexplore isn't associated with html files.

Assuming the user hasn't uninstalled it, how safe is it to do so without supplying a path to the program.  This works on my machine, i.e. the default Windows search path  contains a path to iexplore.exe.  Is it reasonable to expect this on all recent Windows (XP+) machines?

Is there a safer way to ShellExecute iexplore.exe?

(Delphi XE2)

(Although this question stands alone, I'll giving the user the option to run IE in the context of this SO question I asked at the same time: [Detect Chrome as browser associated with html files in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962753/detect-chrome-as-browser-is-associated-with-html-files-in-windows))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'iexplore.exe' is not in the default search path. It's path is registered in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\IEXPLORE.EXE` key. If this key, for any reason, is missing or pointing to a wrong location, your approach won't work. I would think the probability of this happening would be quite low.

As one alternative, you can use Internet Explorer object. With a broken registry or similar, this may also fail, but it sounds like a more official way to me.

```
ie := CreateOleObject('InternetExplorer.Application');
ie.Visible := True;
ie.Navigate('http://example.com');
```

IE Object reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29).

Comment: Wow, I didn't know how ShellExecute searched, Sertac.  Here's a link to MS documentation on App Paths. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx.  Thank you.