# How do I open a file with the default text editor?

Tags: delphi, configuration-files, shellexecute

I want to open a *.conf file. I want to open this file with the standard Windows editor (e.g., notepad.exe).

I currently have this ShellExecute code:

```
var
  sPath, conf: String;
begin
  try
  sPath := GetCurrentDir + '\conf\';
  conf := 'nginx.conf';
ShellExecute(Application.Handle, 'open', PChar(conf), '', Pchar(sPath+conf), SW_SHOW);
  except
    ShowMessage('Invalid config path.');
  end;
end;
```

But nothing happens. So what should I change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is that you use `nginx.conf` as the file name. You need the fully-qualified file name (with drive and directory). If the file resides in the same directory as your EXE, you should do

```
ShellExecute(Handle, nil,
  PChar(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'nginx.conf'),
  nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
```

There is no need to set the directory, and you should normally use `SW_SHOWNORMAL`.

Also, this only works if the system running the application has the file associations set up properly for `.conf` files. If the system running the application opens `.conf` files with MS Paint, then the line above will start MS Paint. If there are no associations at all, the line won't work.

You can specify manually to use `notepad.exe`:

```
ShellExecute(Handle, nil, PChar('notepad.exe'),
  PChar(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'nginx.conf'),
  nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
```

Now we start `notepad.exe` and pass the file name as the first argument.

Third, you shouldn't use `try..except` the way you do now. The `ShellExecute` may fail for other reasons than 'invalid config path', and in any case, it won't raise an exception. Instead, consider

```
if FileExists(...) then
  ShellExecute(...)
else
  MessageBox(Handle, 'Invalid path to configuration file', 'Error', MB_ICONERROR)
```

Now, back to the main issue. My first code snippet only works if the system running your application happens to have an appropriate file association post for `.conf` files, while the second will always open Notepad. A better alternative might be to use the application used to open `.txt` files. David's answer gives an example of this.

Comment: +1 I had not spotted the file name error and assumed that the association was the issue. I will leave my answer since it shows how to make sure that the .conf file is treated as a text file.

Comment: ShellExecute is a Windows API call that won't raise a Delphi exception in any case. An error is indicated by a return value of <= 32

Comment: In fact error handling for `ShellExecute` is rather hopeless. If you want real error checking you need to use `ShellExecuteEx`.

Comment: @Polymorphin On machines that don't have an association for `.conf` (for example the machine I am on right now), the first code sample here will not work. The second sample forces notepad onto the user and I would hate that. I never ever see notepad since that's not my default text editor. What you surely want to do is open the text file with the user's preferred text file editor.

Answer (score 8):

> How do I open a file with the default text editor?

You need to use [`ShellExecuteEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154.aspx) and use the `lpClass` member of [`SHELLEXECUTEINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784.aspx) to specify that you want to treat the file as a text file. Like this:

```
procedure OpenAsTextFile(const FileName: string);
var
  sei: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@sei, SizeOf(sei));
  sei.cbSize := SizeOf(sei);
  sei.fMask := SEE_MASK_CLASSNAME;
  sei.lpFile := PChar(FileName);
  sei.lpClass := '.txt';
  sei.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
  ShellExecuteEx(@sei);
end;
```

Pass the full path to the file as `FileName`.

Comment: I would probably set the class name to `.txt` instead since `txtfile` is not guaranteed to be the registered progid for text files on all systems. Some apps do change it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for that. I confess to knowing little about class names for the shell and defer to your experience and knowledge.

Comment: actually, I have never had a need to use class names with `ShellExecuteEx()` before. I just commented on what the documentation said (that the class name can be a file extension or a progid) and what I know about how file extension progids work in general.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
ShellExecute(0, 'Open', PChar(AFile), nil, '', 1{SW_SHOWNORMAL});
```

in Delphi DX10 this function defined in

> Winapi.ShellAPI