# Running an external program using ShellExecute

Tags: delphi, shellexecute

As far as i know ... You need to set the executable program in ShellExecute (like notepad.exe) but what if the user wants to use other external program (like notepad++.exe) to open the file? if this is possible then how will i do that?

Comment: You will start notepad++ executable passing the file to be opened as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply but how will i do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16941743/1699210

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that what you really want to do is open a document using whatever program the user has chosen to associate with that document type. In which case you pass the document to `ShellExecute` rather than the program:

```
ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar(DocumentFileName), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Passing `nil` for the second parameter, the verb, uses the default verb for the document. Usually this will be the `'open'` verb. But not always. So you might instead write:

```
ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar(DocumentFileName), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

If you want to be able to check for errors in a sane way you will need to use `ShellExecuteEx` rather than `ShellExecute`.

---

Your comments shed a little more light on the question, although I'm still clutching at straws. You seem to want to be able to open an RTF file in the user's preferred text editor. Do that using `ShellExecuteEx` passing a class name that instructs the shell to treat the file as if it were text.

```
var
  sei: TShellExecuteInfo;
....
ZeroMemory(@sei, SizeOf(sei));
sei.cbSize := SizeOf(sei);
sei.fMask := SEE_MASK_CLASSNAME;
sei.lpVerb := 'open';
sei.lpFile := PChar(DocumentFileName);
sei.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
sei.lpClass := '.txt';
Win32Check(ShellExecuteEx(@sei));
```

Comment: Yes you are right, i want to open a document. im creating this kind of program where their is RichEdit and two buttons (1st button: Refresh, 2nd button: Open As). when i click on the 1st button a data or file will show in the RichEdit and when i click on the 2nd button the user will specify what kind of editor or executable file will he/she wants to use in order to view the data/file shown in the RichEdit.. but i dont have an idea on how to do this

Comment: You need to take some decisions before you go any further. You aren't ready to start coding yet. You need to decide what your program is going to do. How is the user going to express their preferences? Perhaps you want them to open .rtf as text? In which case that's easy to do with `ShellExecuteEx`. Is that really what you want>