# How to retrieve the file previews used by windows explorer in Windows vista and seven?

Tags: delphi, native-methods

I am developing a Delphi documents management application, so somehow I am giving the user some functionality similar to windows explorer.

I would like to know if there is a way to get the preview used by windows explorer. For example windows explorer creates a small thumbnail for a pdf document for example, and displays it when the user chooses to view "big icons". Is there a way to retrieve that preview?

```
MyTImage := GiveMePreviewForFile('C:\Test\File.pdf');
```

Comment: Possible dupe (first question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829843/how-to-get-icon-and-description-from-file-extension-using-delphi

Comment: Sorry you are right. I reformulated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@user193655, using the [IExtractImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-iextractimage)  interface is the way to go, `this interface exposes methods that request a thumbnail image from a Shell folder`

you can find a very complete sample in this [site](https://web.archive.org/web/20120808135855/http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3806.asp) and the source code is [here](http://www.delphi3000.com/redirect.asp?Link=http://www.delphi3000.com/article/3806/IExtractImageDemo.zip).

check this image

[image]

Comment: At the moment, the source code can still be downloaded from archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20060115070800/http://www.delphi3000.com/article/3806/IExtractImageDemo.zip

Comment: Note that the code above from Hans Gulo works, but is very slow, taking around 500 to 1000 ms :-(  The slowness occurs when calling the Extract function on line 24 of ShObjIdlQuot.pas.

Comment: Both Hans and Microsoft mention that you can call Kill to abort the process, but it's not clear how to do that or whether you still get a result.

Comment: To use Hans Gulo's code in a thread, you must first initialize the COM engine by calling CoInitialize(), then free it by calling CoUninitialize();

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the docs for IExtractImage.  Basically you use IShellFolder with IExtractImage to get the picture you are looking for.