# Delphi: Extract video thumbnail?

Tags: delphi, video, delphi-7

How can I get a bitmap of a video file like Explorer does and display it in a TImage?
(Should work with Windows XP and above)

I think `IExtractImage` interface is probablly what I need.

I have found this: [How to retrieve the file previews used by windows explorer in Windows vista and seven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2916610/937125)
 But the links in the answer to the sources are broken :/

And this: [Implementing IExtractImage](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=74474), But I can't figure out how to actually use `TCustomThumbnail` (`ExtractThumb` is abstract).

Please can any one help me out a bit. and If you have a better idea than IExtractImage please share.

Comment: The forum post is not what you want. There, they are implementing the interface for their own file type. The other seems okay. I just added a comment to the question and answer mentioned above with an updated link for the source code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2916610/937125