# Multithreaded File Preview (Lazarus + WinAPI)

Tags: multithreading, file, winapi, preview, lazarus

Hello all,

i am having problems getting the file preview (the one shown on the right side in the Windows Explorer window) for a certain file.
So far fetching the file preview works fine, but it takes a long time (between 0.5 and 2 seconds). Thus i do not want it to be executed in the main thread (as this would interrupt the program gui).

I tried to execute the file preview extraction in a worker thread, but this yields a `SIGSEGV`.
[image: "External: SIGSEGV"]

The call stack is also not really useful, it only shows that the exception is raised in `ShellObjHelper` in Line 141 (see source code below).
[image: Call Stack]

**Source Code for main unit:**

```
type
    TThreadedImageInfo = record
        fileName: String;
        width: integer;
        height: integer;
        icon: TIcon;
        image: TImage;
        bmp: TBitmap;
        infoOut: String;
        memo: TMemo;
    end;
    PThreadedImageInfo = ^TThreadedImageInfo;

procedure loadThumbnailImageFromFile(aData: Pointer);
var
    XtractImage: IExtractImage;
    ColorDepth: integer;
    Flags: DWORD;
    RT: IRunnableTask;

    FileName: string;
    pThreadInfo: PThreadedImageInfo;
begin
    pThreadInfo := PThreadedImageInfo(aData);
    if assigned(pThreadInfo) then begin
        FileName := pThreadInfo^.fileName;
        ColorDepth := 32;
        Flags := IEIFLAG_ASPECT or IEIFLAG_QUALITY or IEIFLAG_ORIGSIZE;     // = 580

        if FileExists(FileName) then begin
            if GetExtractImageItfPtr(FileName, XTractImage) then begin
                if ExtractImageGetFileThumbnail(XtractImage, pthreadinfo^.Image.Width,
                        pthreadinfo^.Image.Height, ColorDepth, Flags, RT, pthreadinfo^.Bmp) then begin
                    if (Flags and IEIFLAG_CACHE) <> 0 then
                        pThreadInfo^.infoOut := pThreadInfo^.infoOut + 'Extractor does not cache the thumbnail.' + #13;
                    if (Flags and IEIFLAG_GLEAM) <> 0 then
                        pThreadInfo^.infoOut := pThreadInfo^.infoOut + 'The image has a gleam.' + #13;
                    if (Flags and IEIFLAG_NOSTAMP) <> 0 then
                        pThreadInfo^.infoOut := pThreadInfo^.infoOut + 'Extractor does not want an icon stamp on the thumbnail.' + #13;
                    if (Flags and IEIFLAG_NOBORDER) <> 0 then
                        pThreadInfo^.infoOut := pThreadInfo^.infoOut + 'Extractor does not want an a border around the thumbnail.' + #13;
                end else if GetFileLargeIcon(FileName, pThreadInfo^.icon) then begin
                    pThreadInfo^.infoOut := 'Thumbnail is not available. Default icon displayed.';
                end;
            end else begin
                pThreadInfo^.infoOut := 'Error loading IExtractImage.';
            end;
        end else begin
            pThreadInfo^.infoOut := 'Error: File does not exist.';
        end;
    end;
end;

procedure threadDone(Sender: TObject; aData: Pointer);
var
    pThreadInfo: PThreadedImageInfo;
begin
    pthreadInfo := PThreadedImageInfo(aData);
    if assigned(pThreadInfo) then begin
        if assigned(pthreadInfo^.Bmp) then begin
            pthreadinfo^.Image.Picture.Assign(pthreadInfo^.Bmp);
        end else if assigned(pthreadInfo^.icon) then begin
            pthreadinfo^.Image.Picture.Assign(pthreadInfo^.icon);
        end else begin
            pThreadInfo^.Image.Picture.Assign(nil);
        end;
        if assigned(pThreadInfo^.memo) then
            pThreadInfo^.memo.Lines.Text := pThreadInfo^.infoOut;
        if assigned(pthreadInfo^.icon) then
            pthreadInfo^.icon.free();
        if assigned(pthreadInfo^.bmp) then
            pthreadInfo^.bmp.free();
    end;
    dispose(pthreadinfo);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    pThreadInfo: PThreadedImageInfo;
begin
    new(pThreadInfo);
    pThreadInfo^.fileName := Edit1.Text;
    pThreadInfo^.image := Image1;
    pThreadInfo^.memo := Memo1;
    pThreadInfo^.icon := nil;
    pThreadInfo^.bmp := nil;
    pThreadInfo^.infoOut := '';

    // use worker thread:
    //TThread.ExecuteInThread(@loadThumbnailImageFromFile, pThreadInfo, @threadDone);

    // use main thread:
    loadThumbnailImageFromFile(pThreadInfo);
    threadDone(nil, pThreadInfo);
end;
```

**Source code for helper unit:**

```
unit ShellObjHelper;

{$MODE objfpc}{$H+}

{$IFDEF VER100}{$DEFINE DELPHI3}{$ENDIF}

interface

uses
    Windows, ShlObj, ActiveX, ShellAPI, Graphics, SysUtils, ComObj;

type
    { from ShlObjIdl.h }
    IExtractImage = interface
        ['{BB2E617C-0920-11D1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}']
        function GetLocation(Buffer: PWideChar; BufferSize: DWORD; var Priority: DWORD; var Size: TSize;
                ColorDepth: DWORD; var Flags: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
        function Extract(var BitmapHandle: HBITMAP): HResult; stdcall;
    end;

    IRunnableTask = interface
        ['{85788D00-6807-11D0-B810-00C04FD706EC}']
        function Run: HResult; stdcall;
        function Kill(fWait: BOOL): HResult; stdcall;
        function Suspend: HResult; stdcall;
        function Resume: HResult; stdcall;
        function IsRunning: Longint; stdcall;
    end;

const
    { from ShlObjIdl.h }
    ITSAT_MAX_PRIORITY      = 2;
    ITSAT_MIN_PRIORITY      = 1;
    ITSAT_DEFAULT_PRIORITY  = 0;

    IEI_PRIORITY_MAX        = ITSAT_MAX_PRIORITY;
    IEI_PRIORITY_MIN        = ITSAT_MIN_PRIORITY;
    IEIT_PRIORITY_NORMAL    = ITSAT_DEFAULT_PRIORITY;

    IEIFLAG_ASYNC     = $001;   // ask the extractor if it supports ASYNC extract (free threaded)
    IEIFLAG_CACHE     = $002;   // returned from the extractor if it does NOT cache the thumbnail
    IEIFLAG_ASPECT    = $004;   // passed to the extractor to beg it to render to the aspect ratio of the supplied rect
    IEIFLAG_OFFLINE   = $008;   // if the extractor shouldn't hit the net to get any content needs for the rendering
    IEIFLAG_GLEAM     = $010;   // does the image have a gleam? this will be returned if it does
    IEIFLAG_SCREEN    = $020;   // render as if for the screen  (this is exlusive with IEIFLAG_ASPECT)
    IEIFLAG_ORIGSIZE  = $040;   // render to the approx size passed, but crop if neccessary
    IEIFLAG_NOSTAMP   = $080;   // returned from the extractor if it does NOT want an icon stamp on the thumbnail
    IEIFLAG_NOBORDER  = $100;   // returned from the extractor if it does NOT want an a border around the thumbnail
    IEIFLAG_QUALITY   = $200;   // passed to the Extract method to indicate that a slower, higher quality image is desired,
                                // re-compute the thumbnail

// IShellFolder methods helper
procedure ShellFolderBindToObject(const ShellFolder: IShellFolder; PIDL: PItemIDList; const riid: TGUID; out pv);
function ShellFolderGetUIObjectOf(const ShellFolder: IShellFolder; cidl: DWORD; var PIDL: PItemIDList;
        riid: TGUID; out pv): Boolean;
procedure ShellFolderParseDisplayName(const ShellFolder: IShellFolder; const DisplayName: string; out PIDL: PItemIDList);

function GetExtractImageItfPtr(const FileName: string; out XtractImage: IExtractImage): Boolean;
function GetFileLargeIcon(const FileName: string; out LargeIcon: TIcon): Boolean;
function ExtractImageGetFileThumbnail(const XtractImage: IExtractImage; ImgWidth, ImgHeight, ImgColorDepth: Integer;
        var Flags: DWORD; out RunnableTask: IRunnableTask; out Bmp: TBitmap): Boolean;
procedure GetShellFolderItfPtr(const FolderName: string; Malloc: IMalloc; out TargetFolder: IShellFolder);

implementation

procedure ShellFolderBindToObject(const ShellFolder: IShellFolder; PIDL: PItemIDList; const riid: TGUID; out pv);
begin
    OleCheck(ShellFolder.BindToObject(PIDL, nil, riid, {$IFDEF DELPHI3}Pointer(pv){$ELSE}pv{$ENDIF}));
end;

function ShellFolderGetUIObjectOf(const ShellFolder: IShellFolder; cidl: DWORD; var PIDL: PItemIDList;
        riid: TGUID; out pv): Boolean;
begin
    Result := NOERROR = ShellFolder.GetUIObjectOf(0, cidl, PIDL, riid, nil, {$IFDEF DELPHI3}Pointer(pv){$ELSE}pv{$ENDIF});
end;

procedure ShellFolderParseDisplayName(const ShellFolder: IShellFolder; const DisplayName: string; out PIDL: PItemIDList);
var
    Attributes, Eaten: DWORD;
begin
    OleCheck(ShellFolder.ParseDisplayName(0, nil, PWideChar(WideString(DisplayName)), Eaten, PIDL, Attributes));
end;

function GetExtractImageItfPtr(const FileName: string; out XtractImage: IExtractImage): Boolean;
var
    TargetFolder: IShellFolder;
    FilePath: string;
    ItemIDList: PItemIDList;
    Malloc: IMalloc;
begin
    FilePath := ExcludeTrailingBackslash(ExtractFilePath(FileName));
    OleCheck(SHGetMalloc(Malloc));
    GetShellFolderItfPtr(FilePath, Malloc, TargetFolder);
    ShellFolderParseDisplayName(TargetFolder, ExtractFileName(FileName), ItemIDList);
    try
        Result := ShellFolderGetUIObjectOf(TargetFolder, 1, ItemIDList, IExtractImage, XtractImage);
    finally
        Malloc.Free(ItemIDList);
    end;
end;

function GetFileLargeIcon(const FileName: string; out LargeIcon: TIcon): Boolean;
var
    SFI: TSHFileInfo;
begin
    result := SHGetFileInfo(PChar(FileName), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE, SFI, sizeof(SFI), SHGFI_ICON or SHGFI_LARGEICON) <> 0;
    if result then begin
        LargeIcon := TIcon.Create;
        LargeIcon.Handle := SFI.hIcon;
    end;
end;

function ExtractImageGetFileThumbnail(const XtractImage: IExtractImage; ImgWidth, ImgHeight, ImgColorDepth: Integer;
        var Flags: DWORD; out RunnableTask: IRunnableTask; out Bmp: TBitmap): Boolean;
var
    Size: TSize;
    Buf: array[0..MAX_PATH] of WideChar;
    BmpHandle: HBITMAP;
    Priority: DWORD;
    GetLocationRes: HRESULT;

    procedure FreeAndNilBitmap;
    begin
        {$IFNDEF DELPHI3}
        FreeAndNil(Bmp);
        {$ELSE}
        Bmp.Free;
        Bmp := nil;
        {$ENDIF}
    end;

begin
    Result := False;
    RunnableTask := nil;
    Size.cx := ImgWidth;
    Size.cy := ImgHeight;
    Priority := IEIT_PRIORITY_NORMAL;
    Flags := Flags or IEIFLAG_ASYNC;

    ////////////////////////// EXCEPTION HERE, but only when multithreading /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    GetLocationRes := XtractImage.GetLocation(Buf, sizeof(Buf), Priority, Size, ImgColorDepth, Flags);

    if (GetLocationRes = NOERROR) or (GetLocationRes = E_PENDING) then begin
        if GetLocationRes = E_PENDING then begin
            { if QI for IRunnableTask succeed, we can use RunnableTask
            interface pointer later to kill running extraction process.
            We could spawn a new thread here to extract image. }
            if S_OK <> XtractImage.QueryInterface(IRunnableTask, RunnableTask) then
                RunnableTask := nil;
        end;
        Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
        try
            // This could consume a long time.
            // If RunnableTask is available then calling Kill() method will immediately abort the process.
            OleCheck(XtractImage.Extract(BmpHandle));
            Bmp.Handle := BmpHandle;
            Result := True;
        except
            on E: EOleSysError do begin
                //-------------
                OutputDebugString(PChar(string(E.ClassName) + ': ' + E.Message));
                //-------------
                FreeAndNilBitmap;
                Result := False;
            end else begin
                FreeAndNilBitmap;
                raise;
            end;
        end; { try/except }
    end;
end;

procedure GetShellFolderItfPtr(const FolderName: string; Malloc: IMalloc; out TargetFolder: IShellFolder);
var
    DesktopFolder: IShellFolder;
    ItemIDList: PItemIDList;
begin
    OleCheck(SHGetDesktopFolder(DesktopFolder));
    ShellFolderParseDisplayName(DesktopFolder, FolderName, ItemIDList);
    try
        ShellFolderBindToObject(DesktopFolder, ItemIDList, IShellFolder, TargetFolder);
    finally
        Malloc.Free(ItemIDList);
    end;
end;

end.
```

**The actual question(s):**
Why is the image extraction working without multithreading, but failing when using a worker thread?
How can i make this work?

I already started studying [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523599/how-to-get-thumbnail-of-file-using-the-windows-api) for another solution, but i am not yet sure how to do this.

**Useful Informations:**
Source for helper unit code: [How to retrieve the file previews used by windows explorer in Windows vista and seven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911837/how-to-retrieve-the-file-previews-used-by-windows-explorer-in-windows-vista-and)

Multithreading example: https://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.io/docs/rtl/classes/tthread.executeinthread.html

Activating PDF preview: open Adobe Acrobat Reader -> Edit -> Preferences -> General -> check "Enable PDF thumbnail previews"

I am using Lazarus v2.0.10 r63526 on Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.

Comment: For one, you never initialize your thread into a COM apartment. If you are using COM on a thread, you're going to have to [CoInitializeEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coinitializeex) it. Although it's much more likely that your access violation is the result of getting object lifetimes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @IInspectable, that's the hint i needed.

**Solution:**
Add `CoInitialize` before calling `GetExtractImageItfPtr` and add `CoUninitialize` after receiving the file preview, but still within the worker thread.
Ensure that `CoUninitialize` is called even if exceptions occur by using `try` and  finally`.

Working source code for main unit with worker thread:

```
type
    TThreadedImageInfo = record
        fileName: String;
        width: integer;
        height: integer;
        icon: TIcon;
        image: TImage;
        bmp: TBitmap;
        infoOut: String;
        memo: TMemo;
    end;
    PThreadedImageInfo = ^TThreadedImageInfo;

procedure loadThumbnailImageFromFile(aData: Pointer);
var
    XtractImage: IExtractImage;
    ColorDepth: integer;
    Flags: DWORD;
    RT: IRunnableTask;

    FileName: string;
    pThreadInfo: PThreadedImageInfo;
begin
    pThreadInfo := PThreadedImageInfo(aData);
    if assigned(pThreadInfo) then begin
        FileName := pThreadInfo^.fileName;
        ColorDepth := 32;
        Flags := IEIFLAG_ASPECT or IEIFLAG_QUALITY or IEIFLAG_ORIGSIZE;     // = 580

        if FileExists(FileName) then begin
            CoInitialize(nil);
            try
                if GetExtractImageItfPtr(FileName, XTractImage) then begin
                    if ExtractImageGetFileThumbnail(XtractImage, pthreadinfo^.Image.Width,
                            pthreadinfo^.Image.Height, ColorDepth, Flags, RT, pthreadinfo^.Bmp) then begin
                        if (Flags and IEIFLAG_CACHE) <> 0 then
                            pThreadInfo^.infoOut := pThreadInfo^.infoOut + 'Extractor does not cache the thumbnail.' + #13;
                        if (Flags and IEIFLAG_GLEAM) <> 0 then
                            pThreadInfo^.infoOut := pThreadInfo^.infoOut + 'The image has a gleam.' + #13;
                        if (Flags and IEIFLAG_NOSTAMP) <> 0 then
                            pThreadInfo^.infoOut := pThreadInfo^.infoOut + 'Extractor does not want an icon stamp on the thumbnail.' + #13;
                        if (Flags and IEIFLAG_NOBORDER) <> 0 then
                            pThreadInfo^.infoOut := pThreadInfo^.infoOut + 'Extractor does not want an a border around the thumbnail.' + #13;
                    end else if GetFileLargeIcon(FileName, pThreadInfo^.icon) then begin
                        pThreadInfo^.infoOut := 'Thumbnail is not available. Default icon displayed.';
                    end;
                end else begin
                    pThreadInfo^.infoOut := 'Error loading IExtractImage.';
                end;
            finally
                CoUninitialize;
            end;
        end else begin
            pThreadInfo^.infoOut := 'Error: File does not exist.';
        end;
    end;
end;

procedure threadDone(Sender: TObject; aData: Pointer);
var
    pThreadInfo: PThreadedImageInfo;
begin
    pthreadInfo := PThreadedImageInfo(aData);
    if assigned(pThreadInfo) then begin
        if assigned(pthreadInfo^.Bmp) then begin
            pthreadinfo^.Image.Picture.Assign(pthreadInfo^.Bmp);
        end else if assigned(pthreadInfo^.icon) then begin
            pthreadinfo^.Image.Picture.Assign(pthreadInfo^.icon);
        end else begin
            pThreadInfo^.Image.Picture.Assign(nil);
        end;
        if assigned(pThreadInfo^.memo) then
            pThreadInfo^.memo.Lines.Text := pThreadInfo^.infoOut;
        if assigned(pthreadInfo^.icon) then
            pthreadInfo^.icon.free();
        if assigned(pthreadInfo^.bmp) then
            pthreadInfo^.bmp.free();
    end;
    dispose(pthreadinfo);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    pThreadInfo: PThreadedImageInfo;
begin
    new(pThreadInfo);
    pThreadInfo^.fileName := Edit1.Text;
    pThreadInfo^.image := Image1;
    pThreadInfo^.memo := Memo1;
    pThreadInfo^.icon := nil;
    pThreadInfo^.bmp := nil;
    pThreadInfo^.infoOut := '';

    TThread.ExecuteInThread(@loadThumbnailImageFromFile, pThreadInfo, @threadDone);
end;
```