# Programmatically determine AcroRd32.exe path and print it !

Tags: .net, adobe

How do i find the installed adobe path on the system through .net code.
Later this path needs to be sent as a parameter to a function which prints
a pdf document...The later part is handled.

But my question is the print needs to be handled any system, but since 
I hard coded the adobe path according to my system it doesn't work on other
systems with different versions of adobe.

I needed a solution to make adobe file compatible on any system.

Comment: Do you want to know where acrobat reader is, or where the preferred pdf reader is? I for one have no acrobat reader installed at all because I prefer other pdf readers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the FileAssociationInfo class to find out information about the application handling .pdf files.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272035/how-do-i-get-the-icon-associated-with-a-file-type) has an example querying the icon, you should be able to adapt it to query the application pa

Answer (score 0):

There is also another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566186/print-pdf-in-c/5566234#5566234) covering your problem with a slightly different approach. Don't try to get the path by yourself, use the operating system that already knows how to handle pdfs:

```
Process p = new Process( );
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo( )
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    Verb = "print",
    FileName = path //put the correct path here
};
p.Start( );
```

This short snippet uses the operating system to determine which application is able to print the file. Besides PDF you can use this snippet for various file types.