# Extract image associated to a file based on the extension

Tags: vb.net, file-extension, image-file

I want to get the image associated to a file based on the extension.

for example: \100xadmin\100xredirectedfolders$\elianf\Desktop\WORK\Query Coalesce.txt

I just want to get image related with .txt extension.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. What have you done so far?

Comment: Do you mean file icon?

Comment: I mean the icon or image associated to a file in windows. Ex: .txt, .docx.

Comment: How do I get the icon associated with a File type? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272035/how-do-i-get-the-icon-associated-with-a-file-type]

Comment: Hi Justin, How can I use the FileAssociationInfo Class?