# How to get the icon path and index associated with a file type (again, with clarity)?

Tags: c, windows

It's a long shot, but does anyone know of a working method to get the associated icon location (= path to an exe/dll/ico file) and ID for a given filename with WinAPI. The point is to create a shortcut to another file (which may or may not be of the same file type) and set THIS exact icon, overriding its default one, presumably with IShellLink::SetIconLocation.

Things that don't work:
-ExtractAssociatedIcon
-SHGetFileInfo
-IExtractIcon

Return random crap with GIL_NOTFILENAME flag set for any of the default file types I've tried (like txt).

There seem to be several topics on SO about this sorta thing, with answers/non-answers suggesting one of the above. This one [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373357/how-to-get-the-icon-path-and-index-associated-with-a-file-type) appears most close to being informative. Their preferred method doesn't work either, but their other notes gave me the hint to try using the registry.

So for the time being, I wrote my own function that uses the registry [[2]](https://gist.github.com/Liniya/0fe663a1d1e9941c84a6be2e0bb10243), but it's also not perfect: in some cases, the registry stores 'positive icon IDs' that cannot, it seems, be used with SetIconLocation.

Honestly didn't expect this to be such a year 2023 problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `IShellLink::SetIconLocation` if you don't want to override the targets default icon. Just point the shortcut to a .txt file and the shortcut automatically gets the correct icon.

Positive icon IDs most certainly can be used with `SetIconLocation`, that is the common case. Are you calling `PathParseIconLocation`?

`GIL_NOTFILENAME` is just something you have to accept, it usually means the icon comes from the system image list. The shell is mainly interested in going from a file/type to a HICON, not the other way around. The icon for a file may even be [dynamic if it is implemented by a shell extension](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797/The-Complete-Idiots-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Exten-9).

You can add `AssocQueryString` to the list of functions to try that will never work 100% of the time...

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to override the default icon. Edited the OP to be more clear. Thanks for the `PathParseIconLocation` hint, I've changed it to use that and all of a sudden it all works now, including the 'positive IDs'. It seems like the problem was in running this code from a somewhat-buggy network drive. Anyway, marking your answer as accepted.